# Python3 Class Error: TypeError Employees() takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

I was unable to find an answer for this use case as it seems my syntax is correct. I think MAYBE my code isn't pulling the import correctly if my understanding (I'm still learning python basics) is correct:

```
from Employees import Employees

e1 = Employees("Bob", "Sales", "Director of Sales", 1000000, 20)
e2 = Employees("Linda", "Executive", "CIO", 150000, 35)

print(e1.name)
print(e2.role)
```

below is Employees:
class Employees:

```
def _init_(self, name, department, role, salary, years_employed): 
    self.name = name
    self.department = department
    self.role = role
    self.salary = salary
    self.years_employed = years_employed
```

Comment: Your __init__ statement is incorrect. Note that init has 2 underscores before and 2 underscores after it. You have only put one underscore either side. ie __init__(self, ...) NOT _init_(self, ...)

Answer (score 1):

just change the line like this-
`def __init__(self, name, department, role, salary, years_employed):`

it should work then